# Why Does The Compiler Add An Unnecessary Local Variable

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, cil

This C# code:

```
private void LoadAssignments(AssignmentType assignmentType, Collection<Assignment> assignments)
    {
        bool flag;
        DataTable lessons = this.GetResults(assignmentType);
        try
        {
            IEnumerator enumerator = lessons.Rows.GetEnumerator();
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    flag = enumerator.MoveNext();
                    if (!flag)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    DataRow row = (DataRow)enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
                flag = disposable == null;
                if (!flag)
                {
                    disposable.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            flag = lessons == null;
            if (!flag)
            {
                lessons.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

produces this CIL (.NET 4)

```
    .method private hidebysig 
    instance void LoadAssignments (
        valuetype TTReporterCore.AssignmentType assignmentType,
        class [mscorlib]System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<valuetype TTReporterCore.Assignment> assignments
    ) cil managed 
{
    .locals init (
        [0] bool flag,
        [1] class [System.Data]System.Data.DataTable lessons,
        [2] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator,
        [3] class [System.Data]System.Data.DataRow row,
        [4] class [mscorlib]System.IDisposable disposable,
        [5] bool flag1
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: call instance class [System.Data]System.Data.DataTable TTReporterCore.TTReader::GetResults(valuetype TTReporterCore.AssignmentType)
    IL_0008: stloc.1
    .try
    {
        IL_0009: nop
        IL_000a: ldloc.1
        IL_000b: callvirt instance class [System.Data]System.Data.DataRowCollection [System.Data]System.Data.DataTable::get_Rows()
        IL_0010: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator [System.Data]System.Data.InternalDataCollectionBase::GetEnumerator()
        IL_0015: stloc.2
        .try
        {
            IL_0016: nop
            IL_0017: br.s IL_0038
            .loop
            {
                IL_0019: nop
                IL_001a: ldloc.2
                IL_001b: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
                IL_0020: stloc.0
                IL_0021: ldloc.0
                IL_0022: stloc.s flag1
                IL_0024: ldloc.s flag1
                IL_0026: brtrue.s IL_002b

                IL_0028: nop
                IL_0029: br.s IL_003d

                IL_002b: ldloc.2
                IL_002c: callvirt instance object [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::get_Current()
                IL_0031: castclass [System.Data]System.Data.DataRow
                IL_0036: stloc.3
                IL_0037: nop

                IL_0038: ldc.i4.1
                IL_0039: stloc.s flag1
                IL_003b: br.s IL_0019
            }

            IL_003d: nop
            IL_003e: leave.s IL_0062
        }
        finally
        {
            IL_0040: nop
            IL_0041: ldloc.2
            IL_0042: isinst [mscorlib]System.IDisposable
            IL_0047: stloc.s disposable
            IL_0049: ldloc.s disposable
            IL_004b: ldnull
            IL_004c: ceq
            IL_004e: stloc.0
            IL_004f: ldloc.0
            IL_0050: stloc.s flag1
            IL_0052: ldloc.s flag1
            IL_0054: brtrue.s IL_0060

            IL_0056: nop
            IL_0057: ldloc.s disposable
            IL_0059: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
            IL_005e: nop
            IL_005f: nop

            IL_0060: nop
            IL_0061: endfinally
        }

        IL_0062: nop
        IL_0063: nop
        IL_0064: leave.s IL_007e
    }
    finally
    {
        IL_0066: nop
        IL_0067: ldloc.1
        IL_0068: ldnull
        IL_0069: ceq
        IL_006b: stloc.0
        IL_006c: ldloc.0
        IL_006d: stloc.s flag1
        IL_006f: ldloc.s flag1
        IL_0071: brtrue.s IL_007c

        IL_0073: nop
        IL_0074: ldloc.1
        IL_0075: callvirt instance void [System]System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent::Dispose()
        IL_007a: nop
        IL_007b: nop

        IL_007c: nop
        IL_007d: endfinally
    }

    IL_007e: nop
    IL_007f: ret
}
```

Why does the MSIL add the flag1, continue to perform the same logic to set flag, set flag1 to flag and finally, check for !flag1.  This seems like a compiler inefficiency to me.

UPDATE:  I was using Telerik's JustDecompile and while the results are quite different from ILDASM, the additional boolean is still created in debug mode.

Also, I modified the code by removing the boolean completely and the debug version still adds a boolean.  I'm really looking for why the compiler does this.

Comment: What happens if you compile in Release mode instead of Debug mode?

Comment: The actual variable name resembles "CS$4$0000", not "flag1".  And it *does* get optimized away in the release build.  Not sure what disassembler you are using but it sounds borken.  Use ildasm.exe to see this.

Comment: Hans and Michael - you guys are correct.  I must have made a mistaken when I disassembled the release build.  Still, it's not that the release version optimized, it's that the debug version added to it.  So, is the second boolean required for debugging purposes, or is this a bug in the compiler when debug is flagged?  I don't see a need for the second boolean.

Comment: There is none, that's why it got optimized away.  There isn't any reason to generate the temporary in the debug build either, but that's the way compilers work, it *might* have been needed if the code looked differently.  They are a bit bone-headed unless you ask them to work harder.  Which you do with the /optimize option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a temporary local is created to hold the results of the comparison (i.e. disposable == null).

Trying this example:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
       if (1 == 1) return;
   }
}
```

..is producing the following IL on my box (Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (bool V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  br.s       IL_0005
  IL_0005:  ret
}
```

local V_0 is created, even though it's actually not used. I believe it's an obvious optimisation even for 'non' optimized compilation :) ..or more likely: all necessary code is generated to enable debugging. I don't know how it might be used in a debugging session, but it's my best guess.

When compiled **optimized** (i.e. Release configuration) I don't see the extra local.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a similar program, the extra variable did not appear in release mode.  Same in assembly view, debugging showed the extra variable being set ([ebp-44h]) and release did not:

**Debug:**

[image]

**Release:**

[image]

Comment: You seem to have skipped over the first word of the title.